# "match_tool" enchant check for entity loot table?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I would like to have shulkers be able to drop a second shell IF and ONLY IF they are killed with looting 4. I cannot seem to figure out how to do that. The only thing I can think of is having a "random chance with looting" table with a base chance of 0, but it only allows me to assign a number to be calculated per level, not only 4+.

Blocks are able to have a "table_bonus" which means you can assign custom values/chances based on the level of fortune. In the working loot table below (for gravel), I have made it so there is a 100% chance of getting flint with fortune 4. Can I do something similar for looting?

```
{
  "type": "minecraft:block",
  "pools": [
    {
      "rolls": 1,
      "bonus_rolls": 0,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "minecraft:alternatives",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "minecraft:item",
              "name": "minecraft:gravel",
              "conditions": [
                {
                  "condition": "minecraft:match_tool",
                  "predicate": {
                    "enchantments": [
                      {
                        "enchantment": "minecraft:silk_touch",
                        "levels": {
                          "min": 1
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "minecraft:alternatives",
              "children": [
                {
                  "type": "minecraft:item",
                  "name": "minecraft:flint",
                  "conditions": [
                    {
                      "condition": "minecraft:table_bonus",
                      "enchantment": "minecraft:fortune",
                      "chances": [
                        0.08,
                        0.15,
                        0.2,
                        0.3,
                        1
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "type": "minecraft:item",
                  "name": "minecraft:gravel"
                }
              ],
              "conditions": [
                {
                  "condition": "minecraft:survives_explosion"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out.

As you can see, I just used the same check that creepers use when dropping discs (killer), and then I can specify killer nbt:

```
{
  "type": "minecraft:entity",
  "pools": [
    {
      "rolls": 1,
      "bonus_rolls": 0,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "name": "minecraft:shulker_shell",
          "conditions": [
            {
              "condition": "minecraft:random_chance_with_looting",
              "chance": 0.3,
              "looting_multiplier": 0.05
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "rolls": 1,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "name": "minecraft:shulker_shell",
          "conditions": [
            {
              "condition": "minecraft:entity_properties",
              "entity": "killer",
              "predicate": {
                "type": "minecraft:player",
                "equipment": {
                  "mainhand": {
                    "enchantments": [
                      {
                        "enchantment": "minecraft:looting",
                        "levels": 4
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this in game, nor have I made any loot tables before. I have just studied the format.

This loot table has a pool of one, which has two alternatives. The first has the condition that the tool (or in this case weapon) is enchanted with looting 4+, and the item modifier to set the count to 2. The second alternative is the default to give you one shell. The game will pick the first alternative that matches.

```
{
  "pools": [
    {
      "rolls": 1,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "alternatives",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "item",
              "name": "minecraft:shulker_shell",
              "conditions": [
                {
                  "condition": "match_tool",
                  "predicate": {
                    "enchantments": [
                      {
                        "enchantment": "looting",
                        "levels": {
                          "range_min": 4
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              "functions": [
                  {
                    "function": "set_count",
                    "count": 2
                  }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "item",
              "name": "minecraft:shulker_shell"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I found these resources helpful:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/introductiontoloottables
- https://minecraft.wiki/w/Loot_table

Comment: Apparently match tool is not a valid tag for entities, so thats what prompted this question.

Comment: the problem with this is that the first resource is for Bedrock, not Java, which are two entirely different fruits.